# Installing custom font into WP not working

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

So, I am trying to use the [Rubik Mono One](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Rubik+Mono+One?preview.text_type=custom) font on a website of mine, but it won't show up for anyone. I use @font face and tried clearing my cache ant it still did not work, here is the css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Rubik Mono One';
src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/rubikmonoone/v9/UqyJK8kPP3hjw6ANTdfRk9YSN983TKU.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

Comment: Perhaps remove the double entry where it says src: src: change to src: ? Also should the font-family be rubikmonoone instead of Rubik Mono One ?

Comment: oops I made a typo, sorry. I still tried it again but it did not work..

Answer (score 2):

I just made 3 different tests with 3 different fonts including [Rubik Mono One](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Rubik+Mono+One?preview.text_type=custom) and everything is working fine.

- Either you're enqueuing it badly. eg: You're not using `<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">`.
- Or you're using some kind of framework like Bootstrap which is taking priority over your font.

---

### Understanding dependencies and sequential order

Wordpress let you specify a dependency array upon script enqueuing.

> `$deps` (string[]) (Optional) An array of registered stylesheet handles this stylesheet depends on. Default value: array()

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Your `css` enqueuing order should look like this:

> framework `→` google font `→` stylesheet

If your stylesheet is enqueued last, your defined style will be higher up in the firing sequence.

As I mentioned, we also need to add `<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">` for Google Font to actually work. We can do just that by using `style_loader_tag` wordpress filter, which will filters the HTML link tag of our enqueued Google Font.

Here is the final code. Do keep in mind that, if you're using a framework you must specify the dependency for the Google Font tag.

```php
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_fonts' );
function theme_fonts() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {

        /**
         * Register & Enqueue gfont_css.
         * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/
        */
        wp_enqueue_style( 'gfont_css', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik+Mono+One&display=swap', [], wp_get_theme()->version, 'all' );
        
        /**
         * Add mandatory Google Font rel='preconnect' <link> and required attributes to gfont_css
         * Filters the HTML link tag of an enqueued style & add required attributes
         * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/style_loader_tag/
         */
        add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'data_gfont_css', 10, 3 );
        function data_gfont_css( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
            if( $handle === 'gfont_css' ) {
                $tag = str_replace(
                    "<link rel='stylesheet'",
                    "<link rel='preconnect' href='https://fonts.gstatic.com'>" . PHP_EOL . "<link rel='stylesheet'",
                    $tag
                );
            };
            return $tag;
        };

        /**
        * Register & Enqueue style_css.
        * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/
        */
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style_css', get_stylesheet_uri(), [ 'gfont_css' ], wp_get_theme()->version, 'all' );

    };
};
?>
```

Dependencies are specified in betweens the brackets `//... [ 'gfont_css' ]` which is the equivalent to `array( 'gfont_css' )`.

Finally we can apply our font to our elements in our `style.css`, and we can add an `!important` statement to override as a redundancy. better not to do it tho if you're using multiple fonts.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Rubik Mono One', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: thank you but how do I add the HTML, I am using the WP additional css feature, I am very new to this, sorry

Comment: Add the html ? you mean the php functions ? You add them to your `function.php` file.